# SSIS ADO.Net Connector Fire Triggers

Tags: ssis, triggers, ado.net

So recently I started using Always Encrypted on a few columns making me to switch from my standard OLEDB to an ADO.NET connector for a simple destination task. doing so has run me into the problem of I have no idea where to set the fire triggers option.

Can anyone enlighten me where to find this?

Comment: Did you resolve your issue successfully?